# Why different execute sql time?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, explain

here 2 mysql query...this is simple one, but select different field
on first select **mytable_city** on second **mytable_planing**, both field fron join table. but query execute with big difference on time

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
DISTINCT `mytable_city`.`NAME` AS `FILTER_CITY`
FROM `b_iblock_element` `mytable` 
    LEFT JOIN `b_iblock_element_property` `mytable_planing_id` 
        ON `mytable`.`ID` = `mytable_planing_id`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`
        AND `mytable_planing_id`.`IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID` = 70
    INNER JOIN `b_iblock_element` `mytable_planing` 
        ON `mytable_planing_id`.`VALUE_HASH` = `mytable_planing`.`XML_HASH`
    LEFT JOIN `b_iblock_element_property` `mytable_housetype_id` 
        ON `mytable_planing`.`ID` = `mytable_housetype_id`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`
        AND `mytable_housetype_id`.`IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID` = 46
    INNER JOIN `b_iblock_element` `mytable_housetype` 
        ON `mytable_housetype_id`.`VALUE_HASH` = `mytable_housetype`.`XML_HASH`
    LEFT JOIN `b_iblock_element_prop_s4` `mytable_street_id` 
        ON `mytable_street_id`.`PROP_60_HASH` = `mytable_housetype`.`XML_HASH`
    INNER JOIN `b_iblock_element` `mytable_street` 
        ON `mytable_street_id`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID` = `mytable_street`.`ID`
    LEFT JOIN `b_iblock_section` `mytable_city` 
        ON `mytable_street`.`IBLOCK_SECTION_ID` = `mytable_city`.`ID`
    INNER JOIN `b_iblock_element_property` `mytable_archive` 
        ON `mytable`.`ID` = `mytable_archive`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`
        AND `mytable_archive`.`IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID` = 321
    WHERE `mytable`.`IBLOCK_ID` = 7
        AND (`mytable_archive`.`VALUE_NUM` IS NULL OR `mytable_archive`.`VALUE_NUM` = 0)
        AND (`mytable_city`.`NAME` IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(`mytable_city`.`NAME`) > 0)
```

Time: 1.82977 sec

EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type     table               type    possible_keys                   key                     key_len     ref                                                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      mytable_housetype_id    ref     IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID              IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID              4   const                                                   4   Using where; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE      mytable_planing         eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY                         4   tesserbd.mytable_housetype_id.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID         1    
1   SIMPLE      mytable_housetype       ref     XML_HASH                        XML_HASH                        96  tesserbd.mytable_housetype_id.VALUE_HASH                1   Using index
1   SIMPLE      mytable_planing_id      ref     VALUE_HASH                      VALUE_HASH                      96  tesserbd.mytable_planing.XML_HASH                       15  Using where
1   SIMPLE      mytable_archive         ref     ix_iblock_element_property_1    ix_iblock_element_property_1    8   tesserbd.mytable_planing_id.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID,const     1   Using where
1   SIMPLE      mytable_street_id       ref     PROP_60_HASH                    PROP_60_HASH                    96  tesserbd.mytable_housetype_id.VALUE_HASH                185 Using where
1   SIMPLE      mytable                 eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY                         4   tesserbd.mytable_planing_id.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID           1   Using where
1   SIMPLE      mytable_street          eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY                         4   tesserbd.mytable_street_id.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID            1    
1   SIMPLE      mytable_city            eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY                         4   tesserbd.mytable_street.IBLOCK_SECTION_ID               1   Using where
```

Second some with different select and where on some field

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    DISTINCT `mytable_planing`.`NAME` AS `FILTER_CITY`
FROM `b_iblock_element` `mytable` 
    LEFT JOIN `b_iblock_element_property` `mytable_planing_id` 
        ON `mytable`.`ID` = `mytable_planing_id`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`
        AND `mytable_planing_id`.`IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID` = 70
    INNER JOIN `b_iblock_element` `mytable_planing` 
        ON `mytable_planing_id`.`VALUE_HASH` = `mytable_planing`.`XML_HASH`
    LEFT JOIN `b_iblock_element_property` `mytable_housetype_id` 
        ON `mytable_planing`.`ID` = `mytable_housetype_id`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`
        AND `mytable_housetype_id`.`IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID` = 46
    INNER JOIN `b_iblock_element` `mytable_housetype` 
        ON `mytable_housetype_id`.`VALUE_HASH` = `mytable_housetype`.`XML_HASH`
    LEFT JOIN `b_iblock_element_prop_s4` `mytable_street_id` 
        ON `mytable_street_id`.`PROP_60_HASH` = `mytable_housetype`.`XML_HASH`
    INNER JOIN `b_iblock_element` `mytable_street` 
        ON `mytable_street_id`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID` = `mytable_street`.`ID`
    LEFT JOIN `b_iblock_section` `mytable_city` 
        ON `mytable_street`.`IBLOCK_SECTION_ID` = `mytable_city`.`ID`
    INNER JOIN `b_iblock_element_property` `mytable_archive` 
        ON `mytable`.`ID` = `mytable_archive`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`
        AND `mytable_archive`.`IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID` = 321
    WHERE `mytable`.`IBLOCK_ID` = 7
        AND (`mytable_archive`.`VALUE_NUM` IS NULL OR `mytable_archive`.`VALUE_NUM` = 0)
        AND (`mytable_planing`.`NAME` IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(`mytable_planing`.`NAME`) > 0)
```

Time: 0.00206 sec.

EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type     table               type    possible_keys                   key                     key_len     ref                                                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      mytable_housetype_id    ref     IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID              IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID              4   const                                                   4   Using where; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE      mytable_planing         eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY                         4   tesserbd.mytable_housetype_id.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID         1   Using where
1   SIMPLE      mytable_housetype       ref     XML_HASH                        XML_HASH                        96  tesserbd.mytable_housetype_id.VALUE_HASH                1   Using index; Distinct
1   SIMPLE      mytable_planing_id      ref     VALUE_HASH                      VALUE_HASH                      96  tesserbd.mytable_planing.XML_HASH                       15  Using where; Distinct
1   SIMPLE      mytable                 eq_ref  PRIMARY,ix_iblock_element_1     PRIMARY                         4   tesserbd.mytable_planing_id.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID           1   Using where; Distinct
1   SIMPLE      mytable_archive         ref     ix_iblock_element_property_1    ix_iblock_element_property_1    8   tesserbd.mytable_planing_id.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID,const     1   Using where; Distinct
1   SIMPLE      mytable_street_id       ref     PROP_60_HASH                    PROP_60_HASH                    96  tesserbd.mytable_housetype_id.VALUE_HASH                185 Using where; Distinct
1   SIMPLE      mytable_street          eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY                         4   tesserbd.mytable_street_id.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID            1   Distinct
1   SIMPLE      mytable_city            eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY                         4   tesserbd.mytable_street.IBLOCK_SECTION_ID               1   Using index; Distinct
```

different only on extra - first without distinct

Why?

I try add index on different field and combination of field - but no result given.

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: simple rule of thumb for indexes: any field used in a "decision" context in a query should be indexed. that means if a field is used in a `where`, `join`, `order by`, etc... should be indexed.

Comment: @MarcB im know it, all field have index on each one and on some combination like IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID, IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID for this  ON `mytable_planing`.`ID` = `mytable_housetype_id`.`IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`
        AND `mytable_housetype_id`.`IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID` = 46

Answer (score 0):

in the second the explain plan show

```
1   SIMPLE mytable_city  ........  Using index; Distinct
```

in the first

```
1   SIMPLE      mytable_city        Using where
```

This mean that in the second you access to some column store (also) in index .. in the firts not ..

Using and index or not is important for performance / execution time

In the first you select

> `mytable_city`

```
`mytable_city`.`NAME` AS `FILTER_CITY`
```

in the second you select

> `mytable_planing`

`mytable_planing`.`NAME` AS `FILTER_CITY`

you select date for different table ..

Comment: But both query use same column and table...different only on return fields. why second use index but first not..
Explain difference only one row position and extra field.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just add a few conditions.  Thx All